# Laravel Eloquent ORM Transactions: Why we need ROLLBACK?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

Why we need `DB::rollback()` when we can execute multiple queries without using it. Such as follows:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
 //database queries here

 //even if any errors pop up here, it won't reach DB::commit() and code won't get committed
DB::commit();
```

In the above case, **even if any statement fails, commit will never hit**, and the transaction won't process. So rollback isn't needed or mandatory?

Comment: So you are asking here why MySQL need/requires ROLLBACK.. Also ideally that code could be in try catch blocks..

Comment: Yes. I know it must be in try-catch. I'm just setting up an example. But still is rollback mandatory?

Comment: *"But still is rollback mandatory?"* After looking in some source code part off MySQL server... MySQL (innoDB) does a implict `ROLLBACK` on deadlocks and or when possible (SQL) errors happens on the executing thread like i would have expected.. So no it's not mandatory but it can't hurt to do a explicit `ROLLBACK` (`DB::rollback()`) aswell... in fact i advice you to run `DB::rollback()` in the code so the code becomes more clear what happens under the hood..

Comment: Say you've 100 queries in a transaction, they all succeed, but a different part of the system produced an error, like mail sending failed or payment failed, or something else goes wrong which has nothing to do with the database. Now you want to clean up and revert the changes made by these 100 queries. Instead of cleaning up manually, you simply `ROLLBACK;` and your DB's state is rolled back.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thankyou very much for the info!

Comment: @N.B. I got your point. But in normal flow, it isn't needed?

Comment: Indeed @N.B. but then making [SAVEPOINT(S)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/savepoint.html) / `ROLLBACK [WORK] TO [SAVEPOINT] identifier` could make more sense in those cases when process handling works in status change stages for example ...  If all emails are sended without error but all payments failed you don't want to `ROLLBACK` to a state status where the emails where not send .... Users of anny website/service get irritated when they get duplicate emails when you need to rerun the process..

Comment: *"But in normal flow, it isn't needed?"*  Define normal  flow, which i find normal flow to program you could consider abnormal, what you need depends totally on your usercase and process handling

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I didn't go into details purposely, I just wanted to give an example why you'd use a `ROLLBACK`. The example is deliberately made simple.

Answer (score 2):

Rollbacks, in general, are not used so that your current flow stops if some error occurs but they are used so that whatever changes you have done regarding transaction or DB till the point of error can be undone.

So, it is not mandatory, but it is highly advisable for only keeping the relevant data.

Comment: *"Rollbacks, in general, are not used so that your current flow stops if some error occurs."* MySQL (innoDB) does a implict `ROLLBACK` on deadlocks and or when possible (SQL) errors happens on the executing thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use of Rollback:-

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try{
  //save in table 1

  //save in table 2

  //save in table 3....with a sql error
DB::commit();
}catch(){

DB::rollback(); //if rollback due to error occurs in query 3 then no data will be saved in table 1 and 2...Not Mandatory

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ROLLBACK
In my case I use rollback when I use payment process like I have to create user with full information after that user have to pay registration fees using Paypal account , if it fails to pay user information will be rollback